# Install Windows7 side by side with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, windows, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Windows 7 after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-7-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

I had a Windows OS on my machine. One time, when I tried installing Kubuntu 12.04, I messed up the whole computer and it wouldn't boot up anymore. So, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 from a USB drive and it worked. Now, I need Windows for my school work. So, I wanted to ask if I can install Windows 7 without deleting Ubuntu 12.04 and how do I install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install Windows 7 without messing Ubuntu, follow this steps:

You should create a partition for your Windows 7 installation, I recommend you to install **GParted** from the Software Center.

After you create your partition, install Windows 7 in the new partition.

Reboot, you should see that you no longer boot into Ubuntu, but in Windows 7, to boot into Ubuntu, put your Live CD in your PC and boot from it, then follow the instructions provided [**here**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

If everything is done correctly, you should be able to choose the OS you want to boot from GRUB menu every time you turn on your computer.